# How to print the value of a variable by name in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to know how to print variable value when I know the name of variable.
I need a little help to put all the pieces together.

Let say I have a=A and b=B. Additionally I have list of a and b in file. And I want to print

```
a=A
b=B
```

I was testing with `eval`, but I wasn't not able to do it in a for loop. I guess because I'm not able to capture the result of `eval`...

which I can put together like this, but it smells...

setup

```
$ cat f.txt
a
b
$ a=A
$ b=B
```

execution

```
for n in `cat f.txt`
do
    echo -n $n
    eval echo \$$n
done
```

and wanted result is

```
a=A
b=B
```

but if I need to use the values later it won't work...

What I'm not able to do is

```
val=`eval echo \$$n`
```

to be able to do `echo $val` later.

Comment: You really want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I just wanted to keep it simple...

Comment: It's not more complicated to do it correctly.

Comment: It is correct for what I need, it is just not robust enough for all the case one can imagine, but I just wanted to focus on a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$ for n in `cat f.txt `; do 
>   val=$(eval "echo \$$n")
>   echo $n=$val
> done
a=A
b=B
```

Of course you don't need to use any additional variable (`val`), and it might look like:

```
$ for n in $(cat f.txt); do echo $n=$(eval "echo \$$n"); done
a=A
b=B
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it, when I was trying I didn't have it in quotes - `$(eval echo \$$n)`, maybe that's what @tripleee wanted to tell me...

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$ a=A
$ echo $a
A
$ echo a=$a
a=A
```

Comment: No, you are working with `a` directly, but I have the name in other variable - `n` in example above...